# css: overriding input[type="text"]

Tags: css, input

CSS looks like:

```
input[type="text"]
{
  width: 200px;
}

.small 
{
  width: 50px;
}
```

I have some text fields that I'd like smaller.  I've tried a few different things, but can't figure out how to get specify an input field with, say, width 50.

Textbox is rendered with:

```
  <%= Html.TextBox("Order","",new { @class="small", size = 5 } ) %>
```

Size attribute is ignored, and .small doesn't override the input.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Write a more [specific selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

e.g.

```
input[type="text"].foo
{
  width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that pseudo classes count as a class. So [type=text] (a pseudo-class) has equal specificity to .small, and then the width:200px wins over because of the addition of the input.

```
input[type=text]{} /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,1,1 */
.small{}           /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=0 -> specificity = 0,0,1,0 */
```

You'll probably need

```
input[type=text].small, .small {width:50px;}
```

(As per http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity )

Comment: Thank you for explaining why it was overriding! I had the exact same problem, knew immediately it was to do with specificity but couldn't work out why, you made it clear.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't given much information, but my guess is that you're having [css specificity issues](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/). Try setting a css rule for the following:

```
input[type="text"].myClassWithSmallerWidth
```